# Consider creating a bean of type "[class]" in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have been trying to create a CRUD application but when I try to run the application then I get the **error** "`Field repo in com.nationwide.individualproject.controllers.BoulderController required a bean of type 'com.nationwide.individualproject.Repos.BoulderRepo' that could not be found`." along with the message in the title.

I have tried adding various annotations such as `@ComponantScan` and `@EntityScan` but this hasn't changed anything. The application consists of **three packages** all under `com.nationwide.individualproject; .controllers, .data, .Repos`, with each class in those annotated as `@RestController, @Entity, and @Repository` respectively.

The **main application** class is **outside** of all of these packages at the same level.

The main application looks like:

```
package com.nationwide.individualproject;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication()

public class IndividualProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IndividualProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The BoulderRepo looks like:

```
package com.nationwide.individualproject.Repos;

import com.nationwide.individualproject.data.Boulder;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

@Repository
public interface BoulderRepo extends JpaRepository<Boulder, Integer> {
...
}
```

The Boulder class looks like:

```
package com.nationwide.individualproject.data;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
public class Boulder {
    @Id
    ...
}
```

and finally the controller looks like:

```
    package com.nationwide.individualproject.controllers;

    import com.nationwide.individualproject.Repos.BoulderRepo;
    import com.nationwide.individualproject.data.Boulder;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

@RestController
public class BoulderController {

    @Autowired
    private BoulderRepo repo;
...
}
```

Looking at other questions similar to mine they suggest that its something to do with having the classes all in different packages but I still am unsure of why I am getting the error when the main class is at the same level as all the packages.

Visual of the project structure looks something like this:

```
 ---com.nationwide.individualproject

     ---controllers

     ---data

     ---Repos

     ---individualProjectApplication
```

**EDIT longer Stacktrace message**

```
2019-10-21 14:04:21.705  INFO 3172 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-10-21 14:04:21.716  WARN 3172 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'boulderController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.nationwide.individualproject.Repos.BoulderRepo' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'speedRepo': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'boulderRepo': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'topRopeRepo': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'leadRepo': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
2019-10-21 14:04:21.717  INFO 3172 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-10-21 14:04:21.720  INFO 3172 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-10-21 14:04:21.732  INFO 3172 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2019-10-21 14:04:21.735  INFO 3172 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-10-21 14:04:21.746  INFO 3172 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-10-21 14:04:21.849 ERROR 3172 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field repo in com.nationwide.individualproject.controllers.BoulderController required a bean of type 'com.nationwide.individualproject.Repos.BoulderRepo' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.nationwide.individualproject.Repos.BoulderRepo' in your configuration.
```

Comment: share the project structure.

Comment: Can you paste how did u define `EntityScan`?

Comment: add the annotation **@EnableJpaRepositories** on your application class

Comment: Project structure has three packages inside the folder com.nationwide.individualproject; .controllers, .data, and .repos. Also in com.nationwide.individualproject is the main application class.

Comment: Adding @EnableJpaRepositories results in the same error as before. The entity scan that I had was @EntityScan({"com.nationwide.individualproject.data"}) but I also tried with .controllers and .Repos just in case that helped but all lead to the same problem

Comment: can you provide stacktrace

Comment: Added to bottom of the question now

Comment: one first look nothing seems, wrong can you put a dummy on github

Comment: Whole project is now up on github at https://github.com/RyanKimpton/Individual_Projects

Note that the boulder, lead, speed, and topRope verions of each class are functionally identical

Comment: Works for me, all I did is removed all <versions> tag in pom, version gets inherited from spring boot versions,

Comment: All I did cleanup pom.xml, added Postgres dependency as I was using Postgres, and database URL related stuff in application.properties

Comment: Would you possibly be able to share the pom file? Ive removed the ones that I can and have updated the file on github now but it still doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Please post the entire error stacktrace

Comment: Ive posted a longer stacktrace above, please say if this is still not enough as there are a lot more lines and I don't want to fill up the whole post with it

Comment: I was trying to push by creating a branch, but didn't have access, let me share it

Comment: forked repository of your https://github.com/KoolShailesh/Individual_Projects.git, it includes my changes

Answer (score 0):

You have version issue in your pom.xml file
Remove the version from below code.

```
     <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>
```

It should be like

```
     <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
     </dependency>
```

Comment: Ive tried this as well as removing other version numbers as well but continue to get the same problem

Comment: Remove the below dependency and try. This dependency has no role in your code.
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>